# Parallel Builds with S3 artifacts in codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild, cicd

I am trying to do batch builds in Codebuild with artifacts enabled. However, I have a strange error as listed below.

```
no objects found under S3 prefix for dependency artifact pre_build pre_build
```

This is the buildspec file I am using.

```
version: 0.2

artifacts:
  files: 
    - '**/*'
batch:
  fast-fail: true
  build-graph:
    - identifier: pre_build
      buildspec: ci-cd/application-build/pre_build.yml
      ignore-failure: false
    - identifier: build_mysql
      buildspec: ci-cd/application-build/build_mysql.yml
      depend-on:
        - pre_build
      ignore-failure: false
    - identifier: build_rabbitmq
      buildspec: ci-cd/application-build/build_rabbitmq.yml
      depend-on:
        - pre_build
      ignore-failure: false
```

PS: Batch build works with artifacts disabled.

Can someone please suggest me on how to resolve this issue.

My pre_build looks something like this.

Looks something like this.

```
version: 0.2  
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2&
      - echo This always runs even if the update or install command fails
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cd ci-cd
      - mkdir -p build
      - ls
      - echo $BUILD_EXPORT_VARIABLE_FILE
      - chmod u+x export_github_variables.sh
      - . ./export_github_variables.sh
cache:
  paths:
    - 'ci-cd/build/**/*'
```

Comment: What's the buildspec for pre_build?

Comment: Added it to the main question.

Comment: Are you running this in CodePipeline?

Comment: No, this is through a Github webhook. This will trigger the codebuild

Comment: Seems that with the way you define artifacts, it looks for artifacts for all the batch steps, and since your pre_build doesn't have any, it fails.

Comment: So, do you mean that I should have something like a artifact field specified in pre_build as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239443/discussion-between-bhargav-mg-and-gshpychka).